# Formatting Integer Number and displaying the value in view with comma

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to format an integer and want to display it as #,##0.

In View , I have a list

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Application[i].abc" class="form-control input-responsive" />
```

So In my Application Model, I have a property  'abc' 
which I want to format.

```
  [Display(Name = "ABC")]
    public int abc { get; set; }
```

What could be the best possible way to do that.

I tried using

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
```

but am not getting the correct results.

Comment: I tried and with this its giving only zeros    @{      string specifier = "#,##0";
    var formatted= Model.Application[i].abc.ToString(specifier);
    }
    <input asp-for="@formatted"
    class="form-control input-responsive"/>

Answer (score 1):

You can try `"{0:N2}0"`.

Correct me if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: This makes number appear like 20.000. Basically adds zero and     {0:N2} adds two decimal places with zeros. I dont need that I need to add a comma .

Comment: A comma instead of a dot?

Comment: yes like I want to display 1234 as 1,234 or 123456 as 123,456

Comment: I don't see why "{0:N0}" isn't doing the trick then...

Code: http://imgur.com/a/fY4dK
Output: http://imgur.com/a/Oi5DC

Comment: The values remain same.

Comment: Yes I guess I ended up using something like "{0:0.00}" instead of N2